# Need to add elements of an array to a variable of JavaScript in JSP

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp, jstl

I am creating an array for a list of markers of google map. The code works for one `forEach` loop but I need to add elements of a new array to the list as well.

My current code shows following error message on `var` of result2.

```
  Syntax error on token "var", ;  expected
```

**Code for one array**

```
var results = [
        <c:forEach var="cus" items="${customer}" varStatus="loop">[
            "${cus.value.name}", "${cus.value.latitude}",
            "${cus.value.longitude}", "${loop.index}",
            "${cus.value.id}"], </c:forEach> ];
```

**Code for two arrays**

```
var results = "[" +
                <c:forEach var="cus" items="${customer}" varStatus="loop">[
                        "${cus.value.name}", "${cus.value.latitude}",
                        "${cus.value.longitude}", "${loop.index}",
                        "${cus.value.id}"], </c:forEach> 

var results2 = results + <c:forEach var="staff" items="${staff}" varStatus="loop"> 
        + "[" +
                  "${staff.value.name}", "${staff.value.latitude}",
                  "${staff.value.longitude}", "${loop.index}",
                  "${staff.value.id}"], </c:forEach> 
        +"]";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your code for two arrays you don't want to have square brackets enclosed in the quotation marks. This will make your whole arrays `result` and `result2` to be a Strings.
Second, closing bracket is missing for `results`, opening bracket is missing for `results2`.
Third, you cannot just `+` the arrays in JavaScript. There's a `concat()` method for that.

Try this:

```
var results = [
    <c:forEach var="cus" items="${customer}" varStatus="loop">
    [
        "${cus.value.name}",
        "${cus.value.latitude}",
        "${cus.value.longitude}",
        "${loop.index}",
        "${cus.value.id}"
    ],</c:forEach>
];

var results2 = results.concat([
    <c:forEach var="staff" items="${staff}" varStatus="loop">
    [
        "${staff.value.name}",
        "${staff.value.latitude}",
        "${staff.value.longitude}",
        "${loop.index}",
        "${staff.value.id}"
    ],</c:forEach>
]);
```